# Inheritance in sub classes

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, overriding

I need several classes like:

```
Public Class Class_1_outer
    Public Property field_1 As String
    Public Property field_2 As Class_1_inner
    Public Class Class_1_inner
        Public Property field_3_1 As String
    End Class
End Class

Public Class Class_2_outer
    Public Property field_1 As String
    Public Property field_2 As Class_2_inner
    Public Class Class_2_inner
        Public Property field_3_2 As Integer
    End Class
End Class

Public Class Class_3_outer
    Public Property field_1 As String
    Public Property field_2 As Class_3_inner
    Public Class Class_3_inner
        Public Property field_3_3 As Integer
    End Class
End Class

...
```

All classes are equal, only being different in the property of the inner class (having different name and type). All the rest are exactly equal.

Is there any way to do it using inheritance, or overriding, or whatever, making it shorter and more readable?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: What you describe makes little sense, so it seems like a bad solution to a problem. If you were to explain what that problem is, rather than just your attempted solution, we would have a better chance of helping.

Comment: I'm working on a project that sends JSON through REST. There are several structures like the samples I posted, but they are all quite similar and I would like to minimize the code, and make it more readable. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using a generic in an abstract class, you can specify the field type in the inner class individually when declaring each outer class.

```vb
Public MustInherit Class Outer(Of T)
    Public Property field_1 As String
    Public Property field_2  As Inner
    Public Class Inner
        Public Property field_3 As T
    End Class
End Class

Public Class Class_1_Outer
    Inherits Outer(Of String)

End Class

Public Class Class_2_Outer
    Inherits Outer(Of Integer)

End Class

Public Class Class_3_Outer
    Inherits Outer(Of Integer)

End Class
```

This allows you to shorten the declaration of each outer class. It works when each class needn't know much about the type of `T` since I'm not doing anything with the T. However, you may, and if you are doing anything specific to `String` or `Integer`, then the unconstrained `T` won't work for you. As your question stands, that is not the case.

Test it with this

```vb
Dim c1o As New Class_1_Outer
c1o.field_2.field_3 = "foo"
Debug.WriteLine(c1o.field_2.field_3.GetType())
Dim c2o As New Class_2_Outer
Debug.WriteLine(c2o.field_2.field_3.GetType())
Dim c3o As New Class_3_Outer
Debug.WriteLine(c3o.field_2.field_3.GetType())
```

> System.String
>
> System.Int32
>
> System.Int32

You said

> ... the property of the inner class (having different name and type)

I realize this makes it so that `field_3` are now all named the same way. If they must be named differently, then you shouldn't be using inheritance.

Comment: Wow, this solution rocks! It's nice. But, as you realized, I need different names of 'field_3' (I need these classes to be serialized to a JSON). But thank you very much for your answer, it's very nice!